# Are you allowed to rearrange terms on the same side of an equation if its subtraction

Tags: education

This is a basic one but I encountered this and was wondering how it makes sense.

\begin{align}
   2x + 3y & = 9  &&\text{Rearrange into the form y=mx+c :} \tag 1\\
   3y & = 9 - 2x && \text{} \tag 2\\
   y & = \frac{9}{3} -\frac{2}{3}x & && \text{}
   y & = \frac{-2}{3}x + 3 && \text{} \tag 1\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as long as while shifting we move along with the sign It is allowed .

Subtraction is not Commutative for example $a-b$ can not ne rearranged to $b-a$ but it can surely be written like $-b+a$ if we move the signs along.

Comment: thanks man i really appreciate it

Comment: Please approve and upvote if you find it useful :)